# iOS: How to Create an Application that Downloads Data from a Server?

Tags: ios, database, json

I wish to create an application that will hold a large amount of heavy data (images and sound files) - I wish to avoid having a heavy app. I saw that there are apps that you download from app store and only after they are on your device they download from a server the rest of the files.

I already started reading about JSON and it seems quite clear, but I have never worked with servers before.

Can anyone direct me to a good tutorial that explains how to create my database on a server?
Maybe some recommandations to which servers and tools are available? - preferably free tools...

Answer (score 0):

You can use phpMyAdmin and mySql  (both free). 
You can find all the info you need to install phpMyAdmin here :
http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/

And you will learn all you need for basic sql here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp